# Which server should I choose when developing web application with NetBeans?

Tags: netbeans, web-applications, server

I'm currently learning how to develop a simple web application with NetBeans. When I'm creating a new web application, the IDE ask me to choose one of the server from the list below. I was just wondering what are pros and cons of each server? Could someone share their expertise in the area?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question piqued my interest, so I decided to put in a bit of research.

- **Amazon Web Services Elastic Beanstalk**: is a cloud host more than a simple web server. It's used for deploying infrastructures which orchestrate various AWS services. From the docs (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/Welcome.html) :

> Amazon Web Services (AWS) comprises dozens of services, each of which exposes an area of functionality. While the variety of services offers flexibility for how you want to manage your AWS infrastructure, it can be challenging to figure out which services to use and how to provision them.
>
> With Elastic Beanstalk, you can quickly deploy and manage applications in the AWS Cloud without worrying about the infrastructure that runs those applications. AWS Elastic Beanstalk reduces management complexity without restricting choice or control. You simply upload your application, and Elastic Beanstalk automatically handles the details of capacity provisioning, load balancing, scaling, and application health monitoring.

- **Tomcat** is simply an application server, ie, **an implementation of the Java Servlet and JSP specifications only**. The question that you should ask is: can I use Tomcat for this project? If the answer is yes, it's probably the best choice.

  Pros: ligher memory footprint (typically less than 100 MB).
- **JBoss** and **Glassfish** are full Java EE application servers, ie, **an implementation of the Java EE Application Server specification which fully complies with, and supports, all Java EE features**.

  JBoss has a larger community than Glassfish. Glassfish however performs better than JBoss and has a very slick GUI-based admin console, whereas JBoss can only be administrated with a command line.

  Cons compared to Tomcat: heavier memory footprint (hundreds of MB).
- **Oracle WebLogic** is a full Java EE application server. It is a proprietary product however.

  Pros compared to JBoss and Glassfish: very stable and robust.

  Cons: licensing cost.
- **Wildfly** is just the next iteration of JBoss, after JBoss AS 7.x - basically, it's JBoss AS 8.X with a different name.

Edit: here are a few other servers which can be of interest.

- **IBM WebSphere**: IBM's application server.

  Pros: integration with IBM's other products (IDEs, services, engines...)

  Cons: licensing costs.
- **Jetty**: is a set of software components that offer HTTP and servlet services.

  Pros compared to Tomcat: lighter memory footprint (circa 50MB), very flexible, very easy to set up.